# Is it possible to get user interests using Facebook OpenGraph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering if it is possible to get user interests using their OpenGraph API.
What I want to get is something similar to the following:

> User **A** interested in **online shopping**, **guitar**, **Amazon.com**, **iPhone cases**, **iPhone Accessories**

So on and so forth...

As of my research, I found that it's only possible to get user page likes.

Comment: Is your example something that shows up on Facebook that way?

Comment: That's only an example, if course the output will be in JSON format.

Comment: I mean, do you see such a list anywhere on Facebook on a person’s profile?